# Is there a difference between order of convergence and rate of convergence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am wondering if there is any difference between order of convergence and rate of convergence.

If the questions asks me to determine the rate of convergence, What exactly do I have to find?

For instance, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n-1}{n^3+2}=0.$

What is the corresponding rate of convergence?

Comment: This note may help you  http://www.math.drexel.edu/~tolya/convergence.